# Does any one know what tools are used to create this video or chart?

Tags: video, visualization, analysis

Does any one know what tools are used to create this animated bar charts?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRvlyEpOQ-8[image]

Comment: I think it's tableau.

Comment: Try asking at: [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). Can use same account there (click button _"join community"_ at top). This forum is for programming questions.